# Unset current property of an object inside a loop

Tags: php

I think the code is obvious:

```
foreach ($programs as $program) {
    if ($program->name == 'foo') {
        unset($program);
    }
}
```

But it's not working!
 Isn't it possible to unset current property? Where's the problem? Is there any alternatives?

Comment: My question is about objects not arrays.

Comment: Is `$programs` an object (as the question title appears to make it) or an array of objects (as the code appears to make it)?

Comment: it's an object. there's no array in my code

Comment: What are you trying to achive with this? The code is not obvious and you did not say what you expect to happen after unset() call.

Comment: @cebe I want to unset an property! I want to remove something from an object but it's still there!

Comment: @faridv I added an answer several minutes ago, did you see it?

Comment: @salathe Yes, Thanks you. I'm still working on it. I don't know what is wrong with my code but it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($programs as $property => $program) {
//                    ^-----------^ added
    if ($program->name == 'foo') {
        unset($programs->$property);
//                     ^---------^ added
    }
}
```